# Virtual File System on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, phpstorm

I am a PHP programmer and I am looking for a way to create a virtual folder/file Structure, which means: i can copy only required files from anywhere (which would actually be linked to the original file) but which works like a real folder i can open with my PHPStorm.

So this would be for example (simplified)

```
Real file system: 
c:\dev\project1\myfile1.php
c:\dev\project1\myfile2.php
c:\dev\project1\myfile3.php
c:\dev\project1\myfile4.php
c:\dev\project1\template\template.tpl
c:\dev\project1\images\img1.jpg
c:\dev\project1\images\img2.jpg
c:\dev\project1\images\img3.jpg
c:\dev\project1\info.txt

Virtual File Structure:
\myprojects\project1\myfile2.php
\myprojects\project1\myfile4.php
\myprojects\project1\template.tpl
\myprojects\project1\img\img1.jpg
\myprojects\project1\img\img2.jpg
```

So when editing my project - instead of seeing thousands of files i'd only see the required ones.

Any Ideas?
Thanks

PS: I'm still using TotalCommander which has a Plugin like that but the Virtual Folder only can be accessed inside from Totalcommander (it seems)

Comment: You can use include paths to include or require files without specifying their full path.

Comment: Create a Directory then create hard links to the files you want, new files in that directory will remain there and have no links related to them, but linked files will properly update their respective linked file. That will allow you to only see what you want, if you want to save some new file to specific path you will have to do so to the specific path you want, or just leave it there since thats the place you want it anyways.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a new folder in your required project directory which will act as your virtual folder and then linking only the those files from the original folder which you want to appear in the virtual folder?

With linking, I am referring to creating symlinks and hardlinks.
In Windows, you can create both types of links using the [mklink](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) command.
For example,

```
mklink /h <virtual-folder>\file <actual-folder>\file
```

The only downside to this is that newly created files/folders in your thus created virtual folder will not automatically appear in your original folder.

Comment: Hard links are supposed to reflect the changes and new files, Don't know why the new files wouldn't appear in the links, they may take some seconds tho.

Comment: @arana with "new files not appearing", I was referring specifically to new files created in the folder where the newly created links will reside. There is no way for them to automatically get linked back to the original folder again, hence they will remain only in the new (virtual) folder, unless they are manually linked back to the original (actual) folder again by using the `mklink` command.

Comment: Yeah I know what you refer to by "linking", But I have used mklink with directory symbolic links with no problem about new content not showing up in either original or virtual directory, maybe it is a problem with the junction which is the older way of doing it (mklink /j)  Have not tried that, but mklink /D (directory symbolic link, only supported since Windows VISTA) I have no problem at all and it also supports UNC paths  so that may be where that problem happens.

Comment: Nevermind I re-read the question and this is not what he wants, now I understan what you mean. But then again, if it is a new file created there then it means it does not have an original folder, the original will be the virtual one, in fact the folder does not have to be virtual at all, only its contents should be linked if they come from other paths, but if it was created there then it should not link to anywhere else.